# classes and inheritance in python

Tags: class, python-2.7, inheritance

I am new to 'python' and was trying out classes and objects.
To understand classes I was trying out some small code. 
This code basically creates a `Hero` with `health` (i gave 100). There are three attacks with damage. The code asks the input *"how will you attack?"* from the player. for the attacks given in `att` dictionary the program must return the new `health` of the player which is original health subtracted by the damage due to attack.

My problem is that I am not able to understand how to return the new `health` of the player after taking the input from the user. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'Input' object has no attribute 'health'.
```

please can someone help me with the syntax.

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def stats(self,health):
        self.health=health
    def attack(self,kick,punch,kamehameha):
        self.punch=punch
        self.kick=kick
        self.kamehameha=kamehameha

att={"kick":20,"punch":10,"kamehameha":50}

#taking input from the player
class Input(Hero):
    def __init__(self,a):
        a=raw_input("how will you attack?:")
        self.a=a
    def new(self):
         for  a in att[key]:
            return self.health - att[key]

#create a player
player1=Hero("goku")
player1.stats(100)

print player1.name
print player1.health

x=Input(att)
print x.new()
```

Answer (score 0):

`new()` is a method of the Hero class so you should call it on the player1 object. Additionally to that you should modify your `new` method (and probably modify the name to something not so close to typically reserverd keywords), to accept the attack type.

example:

```
print player1.new(x)
```

and your `new` method needs to accept the attack type string:

```
def new(self, attack_type):
    return self.health -= att[attack_type]  #I assume you want to modify the health value and not only return the subtracted value
```

Such basic changes should just make your code working but it is far from perfect - you should validate user input or at least check if the attack type is a key of the `att` dictionary.